# Getting a decision tree in R

Tags: r, tree

This is the code I am using and it does not return a tree and I can not figure out why.

```
library(C50)
library(pROC)

project <- read.csv("project.csv")

project$AOI1 <- as.factor(project$AOI1)
project$AOI2 <- as.factor(project$AOI2)
project$LGT_COND <- as.factor(project$LGT_COND)
project$WEATHER <- as.factor(project$WEATHER)
project$BODY_TYP <- as.factor(project$BODY_TYP)
project$FATALS <- as.factor(project$FATALS)
project$DRUNK_DR <- as.factor(project$DRUNK_DR)

size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(project))

training_index <- sample(nrow(project), size = size, replace = FALSE)

 train <- project[training_index,]
test <- project[-training_index,]

var_names <- names(project)[-7]

dt <- C5.0(x = train[, var_names], y = train$DRUNK_DR)

summary(dt)
```

and it returns this for some reason it only sees DRUNK_DR and nothing else.

```
Call:
```

C5.0.default(x = train[, var_names], y = train$DRUNK_DR)

C5.0 [Release 2.07 GPL Edition]     Wed Mar  6 16:42:15 2019
    -------------------------------

Class specified by attribute `outcome'

Read 25732 cases (8 attributes) from undefined.data

Decision tree:
0 (25732/7068)

```
Evaluation on training data (25732 cases):

    Decision Tree   
  ----------------  
  Size      Errors  

     1 7068(27.5%)   <<


   (a)   (b)   (c)   (d)    <-classified as
  ----  ----  ----  ----
 18664                      (a): class 0
  6870                      (b): class 1
   196                      (c): class 2
     2                      (d): class 3
```

[image: head of the data]
Any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]